# How to stabilize the port used by docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have an Node.js application that I want to run with `docker-compose`. Inside the container it listens for port `4321`, set by an environment variable.

This port is also exposed by my `Dockerfile` and I specify it like so in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
    previewcrawler:
        image: previewcrawler
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
        ports:
            - 4321:4321
            - 9229:9229
        command: ['node', '--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229', 'dist/index.js']
```

I run the app with a VSCode task, which executes this:

```sh
docker run -dt -P --name "previewcrawler-dev" -e "DEBUG=*" -e "NODE_ENV=development" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -p "9229:9229" "previewcrawler:latest" node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 .
```

When I choose to open the application in my browser, it has some crazy port like `49171`, which also changes every time I start my container.

How can I make this port stable? So that it is `4321` every time, like I specified in my `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run -P` (with a capital `P`) tells Docker to pick a host port for anything the Dockerfile `EXPOSE`s.  You have no control over which host port or interfaces the port uses.

`docker run -p 4321:4321` (with a lowercase `p`) lets you explicitly pick which ports get published, and on which host port.  It is exactly equivalent to the Compose `ports:` option.

This is further detailed in the [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

(That link is more specifically to a section entitled "expose incoming ports".  However, "expose" as a verb means almost nothing in modern Docker.  Functionally, it does only two things: if you use `docker run -P` then all exposed ports get published; and if you don't have a `-p` or `-P` option at all, the port will be listed in the `docker ps` output anyways.  Exposed ports aren't automatically published, and there's not really any reason to use the `docker run --expose` or Compose `expose:` options.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that! I'll mark your answer as correct since it solves my initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I started my app with the wrong command. I now use

```sh
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.debug.yml" up -d --build
```

which works great. The port is also correct then.